# Open multiple copies of Word template document using VBA for applications

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am developing a database application where users open a Word template document and merge this with database records. I have successfully written code that does this for one record where I open a template file and replace items in the template document with DB data. I have tried opening the template document multiple times (once for each DB record), but this opens a Word dialogue box prompting the user to open the second and subsequent documents as read only (not very elegant) and I get a Word Normal.dotm error when each of the documents is closed. 
So, how can I use one template document to create multiple word documents at the same time. Two options as I see them are to 1) Save one doc in a new name before creating other documents or 2) Have one document with multiple pages (one per DB record) but to do this I would have to copy and paste the template document contents once for every record, but I don't see how to do this.
Please keep in mind that I am experienced in database programming and only a rudimentary knowledge of VB for applications, so the more explicit you can be, the more useful it will be.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Based on the dialog box you describe, it sounds like you are opening the Word template, instead of using it as a basis to create a new document. Can you post the code you are using to open the template?

Answer (score 1):

This function will create a new document for each record based on a specified template. I'm using a preset bookmark in the Word template to add data from the database. This sub would run in the database.

```
Public Sub CreateDocs()

    Dim oWord As Word.Application
    Set oWord = New Word.Application
    Dim oDocument As Word.Document
    Dim oDatabase As DAO.Database
    Set oDatabase = CurrentDb

    ' where to save our files
    Dim strDocPath As String
    strDocPath = CurrentProject.Path & "\"

    ' preset bookmark in template
    Dim oBookMark As Word.Bookmark

    ' query with records
    Dim oRecordset As DAO.Recordset
    Set oRecordset = oDatabase.OpenRecordset("qrySomeQuery")

    ' template file
    Dim strTemplateName As String
    strTemplateName = "C:\users\you\Documents\Doc1.dotx"

    ' hide Word
    oWord.WindowState = wdWindowStateMinimize
    oWord.Visible = False

    While Not oRecordset.EOF
        ' create new document from template
        Set oDocument = oWord.Documents.Add(strTemplatePath, False, , False)

        ' get reference to bookmark in template
        Set oBookMark = oDocument.Bookmarks("bkmkSomePlace")

        ' add our data
        oBookMark.Range.Text = oRecordset.Fields(0).Value & vbTab & oRecordset.Fields(1).Value

        ' Save and close
        ' Saving using one of the query fields that is unique
        oDocument.SaveAs strDocPath & "generatedFile" & oRecordset.Fields(0).Value, wdFormatDocumentDefault
        oDocument.Close

        ' next record
        oRecordset.MoveNext
    Wend

    oWord.Close
    Set oWord = Nothing
    If Not oRecordset Is Nothing Then oRecordset.Close
    Set oRecordset = Nothing
    oDatabase.Close
    Set oDatabase = Nothing
    Set oDocument = Nothing
End Sub
```